# Вывести значение массива с ключом от другого массива

Tags: twig

Можно ли записать проще этот код или как вывести значение массива с ключом от другого массива?

```
{%for key1, val1 in VAR1%}
{%for key2, val2 in VAR2%}
  {%if key1 == key2%}
  <span>{{val2}}</span>
  {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для доступа к элементам массива у TWIG есть два синтаксиса. В вашей ситуации помогут скобки

```
{% for key1, val1 in VAR1 %}
  <span>{{ val2[key1] }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

См. также:

1. [TWIG Variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) (на английском языке)

Comment: Спасибо! Ето работает.